# What determines which character gets to use a summon?

Tags: final-fantasy-7-remake

During long/hard fights you get a chance to use a summon after the gauge is full, but despite having summons equipped on all characters only one character can call their summon.

How does the game determine which character will be able to use the summon once the gauge is full?

Update: So it doesn't seem to happen all the time. I have had a couple times now where I can select which summon I want to use, but sometimes I haven't had the choice so want to know why it isn't always a choice.

Comment: Have you waited for all your characters to have full ATBs? I think you need 2 bars to summon

Comment: Yes it happens with full ATB too. Only a couple of the summons require 2 ATB bars. Also, if you dont have enough bars, the "Summon" option is still there but disabled so you can't use it until you have enough bars. What I am talking about is when the "summom" option doesn't even show for a character.

Comment: A post on Gamefaqs suggests it could be related to the battle area. With smaller summons working for small battle arenas and biggers ones for larger spaces.

Comment: Yeah that sounds reasonable, i will keep an eye out for that next time it happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my experience, other comments, and research it seems that this is caused by the size of the battle area.

If they area is too small for the summon to appear and move around in, then they wont be available.

For example, Shiva is smaller then Ifrit so could be summoned in smaller areas where Ifrit might be unavailable.